# How to redirect Vimeo embedded video to anothet URL using onFinish() function?

Tags: javascript

How to redirect Vimeo embedded video to anothet URL using onFinish() function?

I have tried with

```
    function onFinish() {
     window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

but did not work.

Link to Vimeo developer: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS using Froogaloop:

```
$(function() {
var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);
var status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    status.text('ready');

    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

function onPause() {
    status.text('paused');
}

function onFinish() {
    status.text('finished');
}

function onPlayProgress(data) {
    status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
}
```

});

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this modification.

```
function onFinish() {
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```